# Selenium Webdriver (JAVA) - its getting impossible to click on SPAN CLASS

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

Below is my code:

```
//<span class="ui-button-text">Export</span>
```

I tried all levels to click EXPORT button using below code and it won't work at all. Please advise..

```
Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='ui-button-text']")).click();
Driver.findElement(By.xpath("Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='ui-button-text']\")).click();
```

xpath is not working! any other ways are appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the HTML you have shared to click on the element with text as **Export** you can use either of the following solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  Driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ui-button-text")).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='ui-button-text' and contains(.,'Export')]")).click();
  ```